# Hibernate : One Entitiy class for multiple purpose?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have an entity class named `Category`.I used it before for joining with another entity.now i have to use the same `Category` entity for inserting data into `Category` table.

> Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Events> events;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

> Method for insert category

```
 @Transactional
    public UserResponse createCategory(SubmitReviewRequest createCategoryRequest) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Category category = new Category();
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        if (createCategoryRequest != null) {
            category.setCategoryName(createCategoryRequest.getSubCategory());
            // category.setParenCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(createCategoryRequest.getMainCategory()));
            int id = adminServiceDao.saveCategory(category);
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("Success");
            userResponse.setId(id);
        }

        return userResponse;
    }
```

The problem is i have to set `parent_category_id` in `Category` entity for saving data into `Category` table but which column i used for joining the table before.

> Table

[image]

I can set all the values ie , `categoryId,categoryName,createdDate,lastUpdatedDate` in the `Category` entity other than `parent_category_id` which i can't create getters and setters.when i tried to create it's showing the error `parent_category_id` column name already used.the reason for this error is i have used it for joining.

> Help me for use the same entity for insertion also or tell me will i
>   need to create a separate entity for that which am not feel
>   appropriate ?
>
> User request sample :

```
{
"categoryName":"cricket",
"parentCategoryId":15
}
```

Comment: Could you share the exact stack trace?

Comment: Nothing much in stack trace. i used ( `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")` ) for join already and can't declare a property again by using `parent_category_id` like this `@Column(name = "parent_category_id")
    private int parentCatId;`

Comment: So you want to now store a `Category` without a parent or child `Category`?

Comment: I have to insert  records in  only `Category` table using `same entity class` for ex ,  `(15,Cricket,1,2015-1-1,2015-1-1)`.look at my table for columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are going about it incorrectly. In hibernate the right way to do it would be to read the parent Category and have a persistent parent Category object using its ID(`1` in your case) and then set this Category you are trying to persist as `parentCategory.setParentCategory(category)`.

```
@Transactional
    public UserResponse createCategory(SubmitReviewRequest createCategoryRequest) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Category category = new Category();
        // read parent
        Category parentCategory  = adminServiceDao.find(Integer.parseInt(createCategoryRequest.getMainCategory()));
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        if (createCategoryRequest != null) {
            category.setCategoryName(createCategoryRequest.getSubCategory());
            // category.setParenCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(createCategoryRequest.getMainCategory()));
            //set the child relationship.
            category.setParentCategory(parentCategory);
            int id = adminServiceDao.saveCategory(parentCategory);
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("Success");
            userResponse.setId(id);
        }

        return userResponse;
    }
```

Comment: See my user request in question with `parentCategoryId` how can i insert that  `parentCategoryId` which is not auto generated ?

Comment: Oki your trying to say i sholud find the `parentCategoryId` rather than trying to insert the value fetching from user request ?

Comment: You are mixing JDBC based aproach and ORM based approach. In ORM you think about relationship.

Comment: Yes fetch the parent and then persist the child in relation parent.

Comment: it might be the standard way..but , I have all the info which i need to insert ..then why i have to fetch it again ? will i can set directly and insert without `find` parentCatogry ?

Comment: `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.weekenter.www.entity.Category` Am getting the error when trying this

Comment: This can be solved by either persisting the category before without setting parent reference or defining a cascade attribute like `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: Thank u you very much rohit  :)

Answer (score 1):

Look up the parent category entity from your dao and then set the parent entity using the setter for setting the parent category instead of trying to set the parent category id. For example

```
Category parentCategory = adminServiceDao.findCategory(Integer.parseInt(createCategoryRequest.getMainCategory());
category.setParentCategory(parentCategory);
```

Comment: What you mean ? `parent_category_id` is the column in my `Category` table which i should set and insert.

Comment: When using hibernate one cannot set ids in the way you are trying to do. You establish relationships between entities and hibernate takes care of setting the appropriate ids. In your example you have a ManyToOne defined on the same table, so the way to establish the relationship is to lookup the parent first and then set the parent on the child.

Comment: See my user request in question with `parentCategoryId` how can i insert that  `parentCategoryId` which is not auto generated ?

Comment: Oki your trying to say i sholud find the `parentCategoryId` rather than trying to insert the value fetching from user request ?

Comment: For this mapping to work with the data you mentioned, you would have to create the parent category if one does not exist. In other words, thinking of this in terms of records in the database, after this operation completes you would have two records one for category 15 and one for category cricket.